# Devise Invitable: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, constants, initialization, invitation

I'm using devise, which works fine, now I try to use devise_invitable.
I installed it correctly, but I'm getting the error when I try to access

http://localhost:3000/users/invitation/new

The error is:

> Started GET "/users/invitation/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-06 20:47:07 -0300
> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users):
> Rendered /Users/Fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.9ms)

The routes looks like ok, and I don't know why it return this error.

Routes:

```
accept_user_invitation
GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)
   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/invitations"}

user_invitation
POST   /users/invitation(.:format)              
   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/invitations"}

new_user_invitation 
GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)          
   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/invitations"}
```

Comment: Please post corresponding routes.rb entries.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you must stick your invitations controller within a `users` directory under `app/controllers` for this to work.

So you would end up with:

```
/app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb
```

Doing this will get rid of that `unitialized constant` error.

Answer (score 10):

Try changing

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
```

to

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'devise/invitations' }
```